# IBM Message Broker in Linux: Set Broker Port to 80

Tags: linux, ports, messagebroker

We're trying to create a broker in Linux that listens in on port 80. So far, we have created the broker, set the port using mqsichangeproperties, and tried to restart the broker. However, when we use netstat -an | grep 80, port 80 does not appear on the list of ports being listened to. The commands work perfectly in Windows, however, it's a requirement to create the broker in Linux. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Linux in general does not allow non root owned processes to bind to ports below 1024.

Check out this server fault question for more info and possible ways to solve it.
https://serverfault.com/questions/268099/bind-to-ports-less-than-1024-without-root-access